# C# How to get pixel from stretched bitmap/picturebox

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, picturebox

Okay, i have a pictureBox with an image, with a sizeMode set to: StretchImage,
Now, i want to get the pixel that i click. (bitmap.GetPixel(x,y)). 
But when the image is streched from the normal size, i get the original pixel. as in the pixel that would be there before the strech(if that makes sense?)

My Code:

```
Private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  Bitmap img = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image; 
  var color = img.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y)
}
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There should be a way to compensate for the stretching factor induced by the picture box. I'm thinking about taking the stretched width and height from the picture box, and the width and height from the original image, computing a stretching factor, and multiplying these with the `e.X` and `e.Y` coordinates. 
Maybe something like:

```
Bitmap img = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image; 
float stretch_X = img.Width  / (float)pictureBox1.Width;
float stretch_Y = img.Height / (float)pictureBox1.Height;
var color = img.GetPixel((int)(e.X * stretch_X), (int)(e.Y * stretch_Y));
```

Comment: Thanks, Worked like a charm! :)

Answer (score 1):

Divide the `e.X` and `e.Y` with stretching factor. Here is the stretched image fills the entire picture box.

```
Bitmap img = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
float factor_x = (float)pictureBox1.Width / img.Width;
float factor_y = (float)pictureBox1.Height / img.Height;
var color = img.GetPixel(e.X / factor_x, e.Y / factor_y)
```

By doing so, we make sure that `e.X` and `e.Y` will not exceed the limits of the original image.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the original image and leave that untouched. It would be easier than resizing the stretched image and getting the specified pixel afterwords. Make sure that e.X and e.Y don't go outside the bounds of the original bitmap.

```
    private Bitmap _img;

    public void LoadImage(string file) {
        // Get the image from the file.
        pictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(file);
        // Convert it to a bitmap and store it for later use.
        _img = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;

        // Code for stretching the picturebox here.
        // ...
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        var color = _img.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y);
    }
```

EDIT: Disregard. Maximilian's answer is better.